# Syncfusion is causing build errors after migrating to AndroidX on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, androidx, syncfusion

I am getting build errors after migrating my Xamarin Forms project to AndroidX.  The errors are all dependency references in several packages:

```
Can not resolve reference: `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView`, referenced by `Syncfusion.SfAutoComplete.Android`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView`, or remove the reference to `Syncfusion.SfAutoComplete.Android`.    Voltsec.Android         
Can not resolve reference: `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat`, referenced by `Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms.Android`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat`, or remove the reference to `Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms.Android`.    Voltsec.Android         
Can not resolve reference: `Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout`, referenced by `Syncfusion.SfPullToRefresh.XForms.Android`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout`, or remove the reference to `Syncfusion.SfPullToRefresh.XForms.Android`.  Voltsec.Android         
Can not resolve reference: `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`, referenced by `XLabs.Forms.Droid`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`, or remove the reference to `XLabs.Forms.Droid`.  Voltsec.Android         
Can not resolve reference: `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat`, referenced by `Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms.Android`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat`, or remove the reference to `Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms.Android`.  Voltsec.Android         
Can not resolve reference: `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView`, referenced by `Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms.Droid`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView`, or remove the reference to `Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms.Droid`.
```

It looks like the offenders are Syncfusion, XLabs and Sharpnado.

I am not completely sure how to resolve this issue.  Here are the packages I currently have installed on my Android project:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac">
      <Version>5.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>12.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.CurrentActivity">
      <Version>2.1.0.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Permissions">
      <Version>6.0.0-beta</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Refit">
      <Version>5.1.54</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Rg.Plugins.Popup">
      <Version>1.2.0.223</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="RtspClientSharp">
      <Version>1.3.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms">
      <Version>1.4.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.Buttons">
      <Version>18.1.0.42</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete">
      <Version>18.1.0.42</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfBusyIndicator">
      <Version>18.1.0.42</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfChart">
      <Version>18.1.0.42</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfListView">
      <Version>18.1.0.42</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPullToRefresh">
      <Version>18.1.0.42</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo">
      <Version>4.2.0-beta</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media">
      <Version>5.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core">
      <Version>1.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration">
      <Version>1.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials">
      <Version>1.5.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading">
      <Version>2.4.11.982</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms">
      <Version>2.4.11.982</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.6.0.529-pre3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material" Version="1.1.0-rc3" />
    <PackageReference Include="XLabs.Forms">
      <Version>2.3.0-pre05</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

I am targeting Android 10.0(Q)

Any suggestions to try?

Comment: report it to syncfusion support. They always need a lot of time to update Xamarin Forms and it will takes some time until they make the lib Android10 compatible.

Comment: I was thinking I read somewhere that if third party dependencies like these hadn't yet migrated to AndroidX that there was a workaround.  I thought that was the point of the Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support* packages?

Comment: Ugh nevermind.  I added the dependencies it is asking for and now it is magically working.  I know I tried that yesterday but something must have been cached.  I blew away the obj and bin folders so maybe that is what cleaned it up.  But at any rate, it is building now.

Comment: Ok, post as answer what you did in detail

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the compilation error related to syncfusion controls , you can add the below packages in android project

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView 
Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat
Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
```

Comment: The goal is to move away from the suppot libraries and move towards the AndroidX libraries so what is the point in adding the support libraries??

Answer (score 1):

Try using Android 9 as Target Framework. I faced the same issue today and after setting Target Framework to Android 9 (it was Android 10) everything magically started building.

Also I've reported it to syncfusion support. I'll update this answer when they respond.

**UPDATE:** Response from syncfusion support

> We would like to let you know that our buttons (SfButton,
> SfCheckBox,SfRadioButton,SfSegmentedConntrol,SfChipGroup,SfChip)
> controls are compatible with AndroidX support. But currently we are
> facing this problem related with dependent package of AppCompat.
>
> We have planning to upgrade our source control XF to the latest for
> resolving this dependent package issue that will be available in our
> **Volume 3,2020** release.
>
> To resolve this, now, please add the
> required NuGet package manually.
> Manually install Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat

**UPDATE 2:** Issue is now resolved. Syncfusion no longer requires support Nugets